# Does Wordpress need the eval function?

Tags: php

I am considering installing suhosin on my web server in order to disable the eval function. Before i go to the effort, does wordpress use this function? I know there may be some plugins that use it and ill deal with that separately. For now i want to be sure that the core of wordpress does not use this function and will not crash code if i disable it.

Answer (score 4):

Searching the core codebase for `eval(` yielded no PHP results. Even the one in `class-pclzip.php` has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

No, [not anymore](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9602).

A system like WordPress does not need to evaluate arbitrary code in core. For security reasons as well as a matter of best practices.

If a plugin needs it for something, it's doing it wrong.